# Can I undo a OS upgrade on a Mac?

Tags: macos, upgrade, undo

Can I undo a OS upgrade on a Mac? A couple of days ago, my iMac said software updates were available - did I want to install them. I opted to install them. Ever since then, the computer just randomly shuts off. I am running OS X 10.6.8   HELP!

Comment: -1 Because your question doesn't show the expected amount of research effort.

Comment: You should install updates.  The problem you have now has nothing to do with installing updates.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a time machine or other backup of your OS, then I think your only option is to reinstall 10.6 from DVD, download & install the 10.6.8 combo updater, & run software update up to, but not including, the most recent updates. This shouldn't lose any of your data - as long as you just install and without erasing - but a backup of your entire home folder before you start would be a Very Good Idea.  (With 10.6, Apple has made Erase and Install harder to run accidentally, but it's possible for the determined....)